# error cannot find symbol variable id

Tags: java, android, android-studio, undefined-symbol

Im trying to build this simple calculator off this tutorial I found on youtube but I keep getting "error cannot find symbol variable id" , "error cannot find symbol variable menu" and "error cannot find symbol layout" and id, menu and layout appear in red here is the code and please help, thank you:

```
package com.example.khalil.basiccalculator;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void onButtonClick(View v)
    {
        //2 text fields - Edit Text
        EditText a1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Tfnum1);
        EditText a2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Tfnum2);

        //1 result label - TextView
        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Lresult);
        boolean flag = false; //no division by 0 error
        double num1,num2,ans;
        num1 = Double.parseDouble(a1.getText().toString());
        num2 = Double.parseDouble(a2.getText().toString());

        if (v.getId()  == R.id.Badd)
            ans = num1 + num2;
        if(v.getId() == R.id.Bsub)
            ans = num1 - num2;
        if(v.getId() == R.id.Bmult)
            ans = num1 * num2;
        if(v.getId() == R.id.Bdiv)
            //division by 0
            if (num2 == 0)
                flag = true; //division by 0 error
            else
                ans = num1 / num2;

        tv.setText(ans+"");

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private class R {
    }
}
```

And heres the xml:

```
            <?xml version="1.0"?>
<LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/activity_main" 
    tools:context=".MainActivity" 
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"         
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"     
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"     
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_width="match_parent"     
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/Lnum1" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:text="Enter First Number" android:textAppearance="?
    android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"/>

<EditText 
    android:id="@+id/Tfnum1" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"/>

<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/Lnum2" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:text="Enter Second Number" 
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"/>

<EditText 
    android:id="@+id/Tfnum2" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"/>

<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/Lnum3" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:text="@string/emptystring" android:textAppearance="?
    android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"/>

<Button 
    android:id="@+id/Badd" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:text="+" 
    android:onClick="onButtonClick" 
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"/>

<Button 
    android:id="@+id/Bsub" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:text="-" 
    android:onClick="onButtonClick" 
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"/>

<Button 
    android:id="@+id/Bmult" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:text="*" 
    android:onClick="onButtonClick" 
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"/>

<Button 
    android:id="@+id/Bdiv" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:text="/"     
    android:onClick="onButtonClick" 
   style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must initialize all your editTexts, Buttons etc.... in "onCreate" method. When an activity start's, onCreate firstly called so whenever accessing UI elements,  initilize it on your onCreate method

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
   //2 text fields - Edit Text
    EditText a1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Tfnum1);
    EditText a2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Tfnum2);

    //1 result label - TextView
    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Lresult);
    boolean flag = false; //no division by 0 error
    double num1,num2,ans;
    num1 = Double.parseDouble(a1.getText().toString());
    num2 = Double.parseDouble(a2.getText().toString());

    if (v.getId()  == R.id.Badd)
        ans = num1 + num2;
    if(v.getId() == R.id.Bsub)
        ans = num1 - num2;
    if(v.getId() == R.id.Bmult)
        ans = num1 * num2;
    if(v.getId() == R.id.Bdiv)
        //division by 0
        if (num2 == 0)
            flag = true; //division by 0 error
        else
            ans = num1 / num2;

    tv.setText(ans+"");

}
```

Comment: Thank you, this might be a dumb question but how exactly do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

If you carefully you'll see he removed the code from onButtonClick() and put it in onCreate()

He rewrote your code for you. All you have to do is copy that code and remove most of the code from the onButtonClick method and you'll be good.

Comment: Is this meant to be a response to another answer? It's unclear who "he rewrote your code" refers to, but see the guidance on [answer]